# Failed loading rJava.dll using Rscript

Tags: r, rjava, rscript

I run R 3.0.1 through Eclipse and have no problem. I tried to execute some of my R scripts using Rscript.exe but i get the following error:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
error: unable to load shared object 'H:/R/R-3.0.1/library/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  The specified path is invalid.
```

I have checked and the DLL exists in the directory.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks.

Regards

Comment: Could you try different paths, like using \\ instead of `/`, or using something like `file.path("H:", "R", "R-3.0.1", ...)`?

Comment: the first line of my script is library("rJava") but i guess with Rscript the path doesnt work properly.

Answer (score 4):

Solved by Adding

```
if (Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")!="")
    Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="")
```